# PHP Mongo Query to find empty array

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

I'm trying to find the empty-array subdocument records from  a collection,

In Mongo Shell, below query returns 3 records,

```
db.test.find({"campaigns.postcode":{"$gt":{}}}).count();
```

same in PHP returns all the records from test collection,

```
$mongo->$dbname->$colname->count(array('campaigns.postcode'=>array('$gt'=>array())));
```

Please anyone can help me !!!

Comment: Do you use some Yii extension, or just [plain php mongo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php)?

Comment: I am using YiiDBMongoSuite extension